# Error while transferring zipped file from Windows to Linux via SFTP

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using Jsch Library (Version 0.1.50) to transfer files from windows server to Linux Server and I am using ChannelSftp.put method to do the same.

code will read the zipped files from the folder one by one  and transfer to the remote Linux Server.

Same code which used to work before stopped working now.

I verified all the below options .There is no issue.

Renaming a file to a name of already existing file.
Creating a directory that already exists.
Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
Exceeding a user disk quota.

Can Some one let me know where Iam doing wrong

Code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session =jsch.getSession(ServerUsername,ServerIP,rdProcServerPort);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(Configuration.rdProcServerPassword);
session.connect();
channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
channel.cd(ServerDestPath);
File file = new File(zipFilePath);
File zipFilLst[] = file.listFiles();
for (File zFil : zipFilLst) { 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zFil);
    channel.put(fis, zFil.getName());
    fis.close();
}
```

Exception:

> 4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:689) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2871) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2895) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:243‌​3) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:678)

Comment: What "strange error" are you getting? Show us your code!

Comment: JSch jsch = new JSch();
session =jsch.getSession(ServerUsername,ServerIP,rdProcServerPort);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(Configuration.rdProcServerPassword);
session.connect();
channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
channel.cd(ServerDestPath);
File file = new File(zipFilePath);
File zipFilLst[] = file.listFiles();
for (File zFil : zipFilLst) {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zFil);
channel.put(fis, zFil.getName());
fis.close();            }

Comment: Output error:4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
                at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:689)
                at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540)
                at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492)

Comment: Again, what "strange error" are you getting?  You should edit your post to provide a stacktrace (if any). Also that peace of source code should not be in a comment because it loses formatting.

Comment: Also, what made you *"verified all the below options"*? Why do you think they relate to your problem?

Comment: Hi Martin Thanks for the quick response. From the error stack i could notice error code 4 being return when i searched for the cause it is mentioned in the SFTP error codes Documentation that any of the below options might be the reason . I Verified with Nwk team on the above mentioned reasons  but nothing found . So posted in the forum .Can you help me out in identifying the issue

Comment: I do not think that the number refers to SFTP error number. Anyway, do edit your question, as Pino suggested!

Comment: Can you try sftp'ing a file from the windows machine to the linux machine with filezilla or some such?  Would rule out network/firewall type issues.

Comment: @DMHR The error code 4 is probably from JSch. Which version of JSch do you use?

Comment: Actually, "Output error:4" is not how standard Java exception dump looks like. How did you obtain that output? Isn't that printed by your application actually?

Comment: Also, do you get the error on the first file already?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The error code 4 is probably `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.SSH_FXP_CLOSE` or `SSH_FX_FAILURE`and the message _inputstream is closed_ is definitely from `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp` @DMHR Could you edit your question and add the **full** stacktrace?

Comment: @Würgspaß There's nothing like `Output error` in JSch source code. And I cannot imagine how you would get both `IOException` and SSH/SFTP error code at the same time. It makes little sense.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think _Output error_ was written by DMHR and is not part of the real stacktrace. As for the sense: In my version of JSch I can see this line in `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.java`: `throw new IOException("inputstream is closed");` But I sure have another version as used by DMHR.

Comment: @Würgspaß Sure, that's the source of the *"inputstream is closed"*. I just wonder what is the source of the *"4"*.

Comment: Hi @Würgspaß Version of Jsch is 0.1.50

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Please find the full error stack below   4: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:689)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2871)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2895)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:2433)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:678)

Comment: Do edit your question! Provide the other information you have been asked for. - 1) Do you get the error on the first file? 2) Show us a log file of any standalone SFTP client proving that you can upload the same file from the same machine that runs your Java code. 3) Upgrade to the latest version of JSch (and add a full error stack from the latest version to the question) - Note that the "4" comes from `ChannelSftp._put`. The error code is hard-coded there to `SSH_FX_FAILURE` and carries not meaning. So just ignore the "4", it won't get you anywhere.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl    1.)Yes This error is coming while transferring the first zip file  . File is getting created in the destination with no data    .           
         2.) & 3.) Will get back to you on the same

Comment: 1) So remove the loop in the question. The code should be as simple as possible.